# How to handle the loader in a common way(middleware) using RTK Query?

Tags: react-redux, loader, rtk-query

I am new to RTK queries, and I like to work with RTK queries.

In my project, I would like to add a common loader where if any request is running show the page loader and once the response comes back either success or failure, I would like to hide the loader.

Please let me know if anyone has more context on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

Right now, nothing like that is implemented out of the box - but of course, the data is all available in the Redux store.

So you can probably do something like (pseudocode, check with the devtools if I have all the data structures right here, I can't look it up right now)

```js
const isAnythingLoading = useSelector(state => Object.values(state.api.queries).some(entry => entry.status == 'loading'))
```

Answer (score 4):

In my app, I created a middleware inspired by the [Error Handling](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/error-handling) example in the RTK Query documentation:

```
const isSilentAction = isAsyncThunkAction(silentAction1, silentAction2, /* other silent actions */);

export const genericLoaderMiddleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
    if (!isSilentAction(action)) {
        if (isPending(action)) {
            store.dispatch(/* show loader action */);
        }
        if (isFulfilled(action) || isRejected(action) || isRejectedWithValue(action)) {
            store.dispatch(/* hide loader action */);
        }
    }

    return next(action);
};
```

The `isSilentAction` is based on the [isAsyncThunkAction](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities#isasyncthunkaction) macthing utility, which filters out actions created by the `createAsyncThunk` (like `silentAction1`,`silentAction2`...etc.) from being processed by the middleware in order NOT to show the loader in some cases.

In the `store.js` the custom middleware should be registered:

```
export const store = configureStore({
    /*** code omitted for brevity ***/
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware()
            /*** other middleware ***/
            .concat(genericLoaderMiddleware)
});
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit further what exactly needs to be passed to isAsyncThunkAction as an argument?

Comment: @OleksandrFomin, the [isAsyncThunkAction](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities#isasyncthunkaction) function takes an action (or more) that is created by the [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) function. For example, I have a `showAlert` thunk that sets an alert to appear and disappear after few seconds. Showing and hiding the alert is done within a notifications slice. The loader is not supposed to show whenever the alert appears or disappear, therefore it is defined as an `isSilentAction` which is checked by the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for more generic approach like interceptors with axios, using which we can configure loader to request start and request complete/ error. Similar can be achieved with RTK query using wrapper functions over base query.

Following is the solution to handle loader at the global (common) level. It uses `nprogress` to show the loader. Anything can be configured in-place of `nprogress`. But overall implementation approach remains the same.

```js
import {
  BaseQueryFn,
  createApi,
  FetchArgs,
  fetchBaseQuery,
  FetchBaseQueryError,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import NProgress from "nprogress";

// NProgress setup
const nprogress = {
  counter: 0,
  start: function () {
    this.counter++;
    !NProgress.isStarted() && NProgress.start();
  },
  complete: function () {
    this.counter--;
    this.counter === 0 && NProgress.done();
  },
};

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "/" });
const baseQueryWithNProgress: BaseQueryFn<
  string | FetchArgs,
  unknown,
  FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  try {
    nprogress.start();
    const result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);

    nprogress.complete();
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    nprogress.complete();
    throw err;
  }
};

// initialize an empty api service that we'll inject endpoints into later as needed
const baseApi = createApi({
  keepUnusedDataFor: 60,
  refetchOnFocus: false,
  refetchOnReconnect: false,
  refetchOnMountOrArgChange: false,
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithNProgress,
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```